# Why are characteristic functions are not continuous on set C[0,4]?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, characteristic-functions

I was going through a proof and one of the statements said "observe that the characteristic functions are not continuous on $C[0,4]$" where $$C[0,4]= \{f: [0,4] \rightarrow \mathbb R: f\text{ is continuous}\}$$

Could someone explain why that is?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ArcticChar I was just trying to make sense of it from the definition of the characteristic function - surely the  characteristic function on an interval would always be contstant? Or have I got completely confused somewhere?!

Comment: Can you state the definition of characteristics functions? There should be infinitely many such

Comment: @Surb Yeah sorry thats basically what im asking. Sorry I know its a dumb question. I just dont get why its not continuous?

Comment: @ArcticChar I have that $\chi_A$ is 1 for x in A, and 0 otherwise

Comment: Is it continuous if $A=[0 ,1]?$

Comment: @ArcticChar Ah yes thankyou i was being very stupid! That clears it up!